# Rename files in a directory based on other directory

Tags: file, bash, ant, rename, batch-processing

I'm having several outputs of a program that I need to compare with a "expected" ouput folder. But my problem is that the output files always have a different filename.

How can I rename all files in a folder to the same filenames in another folder. Here the example - the expected file structure (can of course change):

```
expected/folder1/file1.txt
expected/folder1/file2.txt
expected/folder2/file1.txt
expected/folder3/file1.txt
```

And my output looks like this (number of files and position is always equal):

```
result/folder1/fileOtherName1.txt
result/folder1/fileOtherName2.txt
result/folder2/fileOtherName1.txt
result/folder3/fileOtherName1.txt
```

I tried using ANT (because I know that), but was stuck, because I cannot select a file by the index (sorted alphabetically).

Here my pseudocode in ANT (but don't know how to continue):

```
<target name="foo">
    <foreach>
        <fileset dir="result" casesensitive="yes">
            <include name="**/*.txt"/>
        </fileset>
        <antcall target="rename">
        </antcall>
    </foreach>
</target>

<target name="rename">
    <!-- how can I access another fileset and take the correct file? -->
    <!-- Here I got stuck -->
    <echo message="foreach.file is ${foreach.file}" />
    <echo message="foreach.dir is ${foreach.dir}" />
    <echo message="foreach.name.ext is ${foreach.name.ext}" />
    <echo message="foreach.name is ${foreach.name}" />
</target>
```

Thanks for any help, it must not be in **ANT** only - a **BASH** script or similar could do the job too.

Comment: How can you tell which result filename should match which expected filename? Do you just remove a fixed portion? Is there some other thing I'm missing?

Comment: It depends on the alphabetic order of the files in each folder. So "fileOtherName1" should be renamed to file1 and so on. 1st file in result renamed to 1st filename in expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
#!/bin/bash

IN_DIR="expected/folder1"
OUT_DIR="result/folder2"

IN_FILES=($IN_DIR/*)
OUT_FILES=($OUT_DIR/*)

for ((i=0; i<${#IN_FILES[@]}; i++)); do
    mv ${OUT_FILES[i]} $OUT_DIR/$(basename ${IN_FILES[i]})
done
```

Tested it on some test dirs, and it works OK.

Note that if any of your file names contains a space, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't know ANT, so I'll give it a shot in bash.

```
for i in *; do 
  k=1; 
  for j in $i/*; do
    mv "$j" $i/file$k.txt;
    k=$[$k+1];
  done;
done
```

This iterates through the folders and increments a counter for every file in the folder. When we proceed to the next folder, the counter is reset.

I created a test directory structure like yours and it worked for me.